# Does Hammer 2.0 allow me to to everything I do in 1.0.5?

Tags: hammer.js

My HTPC project (open source) uses Hammer 1.0.5 extensively - 32 separate hammer instances in many pages; 184 different event handlers; handles many different event types (tap, doubletap, touch, release, hold, drag, dragup, dragdown, swipeleft, swiperight, swipeup, swipedown). All the event handlers use delegation.

When I found I had a glitch on Safari on an iPad (every other touch is ignored), I came to look for anyone with the same problem and discovered I had missed the release of version 2. So ...

- Is it wise to upgrade?
- Can I do **everything** in version 2 that I could with version 1?
- Is the upgrade fairly mechanical? (Set options to enable capability, use new names for events)?

I can't find any guidance for upgrading in the hammer documentation, which is a shame.

Thanks

Brian

Answer (score 0):

Well the simple answer is that "*No I can't easily port my Hammer 1.x implementation to 2.0*".

Below is a snippet of one of my HTPC JS files, that adds actions to a `<div>` containing a EPG listing of TV programmes. This works very well with 1.x.

```
var listingsHammer = null;

function AddListingsHammerActions() {
    $("#guideBrowserItems").each(function () {
        var h = $(window).height() - 24
        var t = $(this).offset().top
        console.log("#guideBrowserItems h=" + h + "; t=" + t + " => " + (h - t))
        $(this).height(h - t)
    });

    if (!listingsHammer) {
        listingsHammer = $(".guideBrowserItems").hammer({ prevent_default: true });
    }

    EnableDragScroll(listingsHammer)

    listingsHammer.on("tap", ".guideEpgProgramme", function (e) {
        var programItem = this;
        $(".guideEpgProgrammeDescription").remove();
        $(".guideEpgProgrammeCancel").remove();
        $(".guideEpgProgrammeRecord").remove();
        $(".guideEpgProgrammeRecordSeries").remove();

        $.ajax({
            url: "/Guide/Description?id=" + programItem.id,
            success: function (description) {
                if (hasClass(programItem, "guideEpgProgrammeScheduled")) {
                    $(programItem).prepend('<img class="guideEpgProgrammeCancel" id="' + programItem.id + '" src="/Content/Buttons/SmallRound/Exit.png" />')
                } else {
                    $(programItem).prepend('<img class="guideEpgProgrammeRecordSeries" id="' + programItem.id + '" src="/Content/Buttons/SmallRound/Transport.Rec.Series.png" />')
                    $(programItem).prepend('<img class="guideEpgProgrammeRecord" id="' + programItem.id + '" src="/Content/Buttons/SmallRound/Transport.Rec.png" />')
                }
                $(programItem).append('<div class="guideProgrammeInfo guideEpgProgrammeDescription">' + description + '</div>')
                cache: false
            }
        })
    });

    listingsHammer.on("tap", ".guideEpgProgrammeRecord", function (e) {
        var programItem = this;

        $.ajax({
            url: "/Guide/Record?id=" + programItem.id,
            success: function (error) {
                if (error == "") {
                    $(".guideSelectorItems").html("")
                    ReplacePane("guideBrowserItems", "/Guide/ListingsPane?mode=GuideSchedule", "none")
                }
                else {
                    alert(error)
                }
                cache: false
            }
        })
    });

    listingsHammer.on("tap", ".guideEpgProgrammeRecordSeries", function (e) {
        var programItem = this;

        $.ajax({
            url: "/Guide/RecordSeries?id=" + programItem.id,
            success: function (error) {
                if (error == "") {
                    $(".guideSelectorItems").html("")
                    ReplacePane("guideBrowserItems", "/Guide/ListingsPane?mode=GuideSchedule", "none")
                }
                else {
                    alert(error)
                }
                cache: false
            }
        })
    });

    listingsHammer.on("tap", ".guideEpgProgrammeCancel", function (e) {
        var programItem = this;

        $.ajax({
            url: "/Guide/Cancel?id=" + programItem.id,
            success: function (error) {
                if (error == "") {
                    $(".guideSelectorItems").html("")
                    ReplacePane("guideBrowserItems", "/Guide/ListingsPane?mode=GuideSchedule", "none")
                }
                else {
                    alert(error)
                }
                cache: false
            }
        })
    });

    listingsHammer.on("tap", ".guideEpgSeriesCancel", function (e) {
        var seriesItem = this;

        $.ajax({
            url: "/Guide/CancelSeries?id=" + seriesItem.id,
            success: function () {
                $(".guideSelectorItems").html("")
                ReplacePane("guideBrowserItems", "/Guide/ListingsPane?mode=GuideSeries", "none")
                cache: false
            }
        })
    });

}
```

There are a few things to note.

1. I only use one Hammer for the entire `<div>`, with delegation to each of the individual `guideEpgProgramme` sub-elements, so that when I touch a listed programme, the handler acts on that one sub-element.
2. This allows me to dynamically replace the contents of the `<div>` via Ajax (e.g. for another channel), with no need to re-register handlers.
3. The Record and Cancel button images are dynamically added and removed as needed and automatically gain the desired pre-registered actions.
4. The Hammer object is passed to a common utility function `EnableDragScroll`, which adds handlers for scrolling the (long, variable length) contents within the fixed size `guideBrowserItems` page area.
5. There are many instances of `ReplacePane("guideBrowserItems", <NEW URL>)` to dynamically alter the contents of the `<div>` without affecting the rest of the page or the script.
6. And this is just one of the 30+ different Hammer instance with corresponding handling.

None of this way of working appears to be possible in Hammer 2.0.

So for now I will stick with the old mechanisms.